# Hive Python CLI Subprocess Stream stdout

Tags: python, subprocess, hive

I am trying to wrap the hive cli (I know I could use hive server) in a python subprocess and stream the output. When I run this query via the cli:

> hive -e "SELECT * from table"
>   Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/conf/hive-log4j.properties
>   Hive history file=/tmp/user/hive_job_log_42a5d7e9-663d-4244-b3e8-0f8ec8af010a_1754850433.txt
>   Total MapReduce jobs = 1
>   .....

The cli streams the info to shell. When I wrap this query in python:

```
def execute_subprocess(cmd):
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, cwd=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), shell=True)
while True:
    nextline = process.stdout.readline()
    if nextline == '' and process.poll() != None:
        break
    sys.stdout.write(nextline)
    sys.stdout.flush()

out = process.communicate()
output = out[0]
exitCode = process.returncode

if (exitCode == 0):
    return output
else:
    raise Exception(output)
```

and execute

```
execute_subprocess(['hive','-e','SELECT * FROM TABLE'])
```

I do not see the hive cli output at all. Why Not?

Thanks!

Comment: You are writing the process's stdout and stderr to the Python process's stdout, so where do you expect the stdout to go? Just use `subprocess.check_output`.

Comment: im watching it in the terminal window. I would expect to see the output. I think the process.stdout.readline() is blocking. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python/4896288#4896288